# How to Create Custom HTML Tag on Editor in `Text(HTML)` mode

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

Can you please let me know how I can add a custom Tag button into WP Editor in `Text(HTML)` mode like

[image]

what I would like to insert into the Post is something like

```
<hr class="dark-line-2" />
```

every time that user pushed on `hr` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a plugin like [Visual Editor Custom Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-editor-custom-buttons/).

Or you may want to do something custom. There's a solid example at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons--wp-30182.